# c# gdi32 bitblt seems to do nothing

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, winapi, bitblt

I'm trying to use **BitBlt** to get regions of a graphics and store them in bitmaps.
But here, I do something easier to understand my problem:

```
        Bitmap sourceBitmap = new Bitmap(64, 64, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
        Graphics sourceGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(sourceBitmap);

        Bitmap destBitmap = new Bitmap(64, 64, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
        Graphics destGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(destBitmap);

        sourceGraphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Red), new Rectangle(0, 0, 30, 30));
        sourceGraphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Green), new Rectangle(30, 30, 30, 30));

        destGraphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Blue), new Rectangle(0, 0, 30, 30));
        destGraphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Yellow), new Rectangle(30, 30, 30, 30));

        IntPtr destDC = destGraphics.GetHdc();
        IntPtr destHB = destBitmap.GetHbitmap();
        IntPtr old = SelectObject(destDC, destHB);

        IntPtr sourceDC = sourceGraphics.GetHdc();
        IntPtr sourceHB = sourceBitmap.GetHbitmap();
        old = SelectObject(sourceDC, sourceHB);

        int success = BitBlt(
            destDC, 0, 0, 64, 64, sourceDC, 0, 0, 0x00CC0020
        );
```

Why after the BitBlt my destBitmap contains blue/yellow rectangles (initial bitmap in destination) instead of the red/green rectangles which should have been blitted from the source bitmap ?

Imports are done like this :

```
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("gdi32.dll")]
    private static extern int BitBlt(
      IntPtr hdcDest,     // handle to destination DC (device context)
      int nXDest,         // x-coord of destination upper-left corner
      int nYDest,         // y-coord of destination upper-left corner
      int nWidth,         // width of destination rectangle
      int nHeight,        // height of destination rectangle
      IntPtr hdcSrc,      // handle to source DC
      int nXSrc,          // x-coordinate of source upper-left corner
      int nYSrc,          // y-coordinate of source upper-left corner
      System.Int32 dwRop  // raster operation code
      );

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("gdi32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr SelectObject(IntPtr hdc, IntPtr obj);

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("gdi32.dll")]
    public static extern void DeleteObject(IntPtr obj);
```

And finally cleaning code, and bitmap streaming to see bitmap content :

```
        DeleteObject(destHB);
        DeleteObject(sourceHB);
        destGraphics.ReleaseHdc();
        sourceGraphics.ReleaseHdc();

        string path = "c:/tmp/dest.png";
        destBitmap.Save(path);
```

Comment: Since you're obviously using WinForms and writing C# code, why do you need to p/invoke the GDI functions? What's wrong with using the GDI+ functions wrapped by the `Graphics` class? Much easier, harder to get wrong.

Comment: @CodyGray Also slower.

Comment: Here is just an example that can be done in pure c# but how can I extract a graphics region into a bitmap ?
And BTW now I would like to understand why this does not works :)

Comment: @Rotem Hmm, not likely. Informal testing that I've seen indicates that GDI is still significantly faster than GDI+. The p/invoke thing is irrelevant in terms of speed—somewhere, someone is going to have to call down to the native APIs. It's always better to let the framework handle it than to do it yourself, but it's not likely to be *faster*.

Comment: @CodyGray From my personal testing experience it was faster. It was a long time ago so I don't remember the numbers or the methodology, only the conclusion.

Comment: As Cody Gray wrote, GDI is in 99% cases faster then GDI+.

Comment: It is not.  The nice thing about GDI+, and the speed problem, is that GDI+ supports a lot of pixel formats that don't have to match the video adapter's format.  GDI strongly favors device dependent bitmaps, history that dates back to very early Windows versions that had to run on a 386SUX.  But you do ultimately pay for the pixel format conversion when you don't pay attention to it.  And GDI+ makes it *very* easy to not pay attention.  Format32bppPArgb is the fastest on modern machines, a factor of 10 faster.  Rarely picked intentionally.

Comment: Most GDI operations are hardware accelerated by driver, so faster than GDI+, but GDI+ supports lots of features, which GDI dont(anti aliasing, true transparency). But this discussion is irrelevant to OP question. For further reading: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjacks/archive/2006/05/19/gdi-vs-gdi-text-rendering-performance.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Found a combination that works...but I don't understand why (definitely not a GDI expert):

[image: BitBlt() across Managed Bitmaps]

I've added in calls to create compatible DCs with CreateCompatibleDC().

**But** note that in the actual call to BitBlt(), I'm still using the original DC "destDC" for the destination DC (not the new "destCDC"), but the new compatible DC "sourceCDC" for the source DC.  No other combo seemed to work.  I still, **however**, had to create a compatible DC for the destination even though I wasn't using it in the BitBlt() call:

```
    private const int SRCCOPY = 0xCC0020;

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("gdi32.dll")]
    private static extern int BitBlt(
      IntPtr hdcDest,     // handle to destination DC (device context)
      int nXDest,         // x-coord of destination upper-left corner
      int nYDest,         // y-coord of destination upper-left corner
      int nWidth,         // width of destination rectangle
      int nHeight,        // height of destination rectangle
      IntPtr hdcSrc,      // handle to source DC
      int nXSrc,          // x-coordinate of source upper-left corner
      int nYSrc,          // y-coordinate of source upper-left corner
      int dwRop  // raster operation code
      );

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("gdi32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr CreateCompatibleDC(IntPtr hdc);

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("gdi32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr SelectObject(IntPtr hdc, IntPtr obj);

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("gdi32.dll")]
    public static extern void DeleteObject(IntPtr obj);

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap sourceBitmap = new Bitmap(64, 64, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
        Graphics sourceGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(sourceBitmap);

        Bitmap destBitmap = new Bitmap(64, 64, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
        Graphics destGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(destBitmap);

        sourceGraphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Red), new Rectangle(0, 0, 30, 30));
        sourceGraphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Green), new Rectangle(30, 30, 30, 30));

        destGraphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Blue), new Rectangle(0, 0, 30, 30));
        destGraphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Yellow), new Rectangle(30, 30, 30, 30));

        IntPtr destDC = destGraphics.GetHdc();
        IntPtr destCDC = CreateCompatibleDC(destDC);
        IntPtr destHB = destBitmap.GetHbitmap();
        IntPtr oldDest = SelectObject(destCDC, destHB);

        IntPtr sourceDC = sourceGraphics.GetHdc();
        IntPtr sourceCDC = CreateCompatibleDC(sourceDC);
        IntPtr sourceHB = sourceBitmap.GetHbitmap();
        IntPtr oldSource = SelectObject(sourceCDC, sourceHB);

        int success = BitBlt(
            destDC, 0, 0, 64, 64, sourceCDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY
        );

        SelectObject(destCDC, oldDest);
        SelectObject(sourceCDC, oldSource);

        DeleteObject(destCDC);
        DeleteObject(sourceCDC);

        DeleteObject(destHB);
        DeleteObject(sourceHB);

        destGraphics.ReleaseHdc();
        sourceGraphics.ReleaseHdc();

        pictureBox1.Image = sourceBitmap;
        pictureBox2.Image = destBitmap;
    }
```

Anyone have any insight as to why this combo works?...

Comment: Thanks a lot, a bit of magic here :) Waiting for insights.
I was thinking Graphics.FromImage already creates compatible dc.

Comment: It's destGraphics.ReleaseHdc() which make the blit "complete". Looks like the the Graphics created from an image use a buffer and flush it to the image when ReleaseHdc is called. Maybe a DDB created with the GDI function CreateDIBitmap. So to blit data from an image, one must select the source bitmap into the source graphics'dc   prior to blit. and a blit operation on an image is completed after the HdcRelease call. No extra in memory dc is needed.